# Passing Square Up amount total

Tags: php

I've been researching alternatives to PayPal for taking online payments and downloaded Square Ups demo files from github (https://github.com/square/connect-api-examples/tree/master/connect-examples/v2/php_payment). After creating an account with Square and installing Composer the demo works fine but I notice the payment amount is hard coded in the demo on 'process-card.php'. So how do I pass an amount from a form input or database value?

Comment: It's best to include a sample of your code so that we know what you've done and subsequently how to help with your setup. In this situation, you would typically pass the value of the form field representing the amount into 'process-card.php', however, how you pass this value will depend on your setup.

Answer (score 0):

OK here's the form page:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My Payment Form</title>
    <style>
label{display:inline-block;float:left;width:130px}
/* Customize the "Pay with Credit Card" button */
input[type=submit] {
  min-width: 200px;
  min-height: 20px;
  padding: 1.2em;
  margin-top: 5px;
  line-height: 20px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 1px rgb(200, 200, 200);
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(200, 200, 200);
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size:1em;
  float:left;
  cursor:pointer
}
input[type=submit]:hover {background:orange}



    .sq-input {
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      padding: 1px;
      font-size:1em;
      width:200px
    }
    .sq-input--focus {
      outline-width: 5px;
      outline-color: #70ACE9;
      outline-offset: -1px;
      outline-style: auto;
    }
    .sq-input--error {
      outline-width: 5px;
      outline-color: #FF9393;
      outline-offset: 0px;
      outline-style: auto;
    }
    .apple-pay-button {
      display: inline-block;
      background-size: 100% 60%;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: 50% 50%;
      border-radius: 5px;
      border-width: 2px;
      padding: 0px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      min-width: 200px;
      min-height: 32px;
      max-height: 64px;
  }
  .apple-pay-button-white {
      background-image: -webkit-named-image(apple-pay-logo-black);
      background-color: white;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://js.squareup.com/v2/paymentform"></script>
  <script>
    var sqPaymentForm = new SqPaymentForm({

      // Replace this value with your application's ID (available from the merchant dashboard).
      // If you're just testing things out, replace this with your _Sandbox_ application ID,
      // which is also available there.
      applicationId: 'sandbox-sq0idp-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      locationId: 'CBASEBbxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      inputClass: 'sq-input',
      cardNumber: {
        elementId: 'sq-card-number',
        placeholder: "0000 0000 0000 0000"
      },
      cvv: {
        elementId: 'sq-cvv',
        placeholder: 'CVV'
      },
      expirationDate: {
        elementId: 'sq-expiration-date',
        placeholder: 'MM/YY'
      },
      postalCode: {
        elementId: 'sq-postal-code',
        placeholder: 'Postcode'
      },




        amount: {
            elementId: 'sq-amount',
            placeholder: 'Amount'
        },



      inputStyles: [

        // Because this object provides no value for mediaMaxWidth or mediaMinWidth,
        // these styles apply for screens of all sizes, unless overridden by another
        // input style below.
        { fontFamily: 'Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif',
          fontSize: '14px',
          padding: '3px'
        },

        // These styles are applied to inputs ONLY when the screen width is 400px
        // or smaller. Note that because it doesn't specify a value for padding,
        // the padding value in the previous object is preserved.
        {
          mediaMaxWidth: '400px',
          fontSize: '18px',
        }
      ],
      callbacks: {
        methodsSupported: function (methods) {
          // Show the Apple Pay button if Apple Pay is supported.
          if (methods.applePay === true) {
            var element = document.getElementById('pay-button-area');
            element.style.display = 'block';
          }
        },
        cardNonceResponseReceived: function(errors, nonce, cardData) {
          if (errors) {
            var errorDiv = document.getElementById('errors');
            errorDiv.innerHTML = "";
            errors.forEach(function(error) {
              var p = document.createElement('p');
              p.innerHTML = error.message;
              errorDiv.appendChild(p);
            });
          } else {
            // This alert is for debugging purposes only.
            alert('Nonce received! ' + nonce + ' ' + JSON.stringify(cardData));

            // Assign the value of the nonce to a hidden form element
            var nonceField = document.getElementById('card-nonce');
            nonceField.value = nonce;

            // Submit the form
            document.getElementById('form').submit();
          }
        },
        unsupportedBrowserDetected: function() {
          // Alert the buyer that their browser is not supported
        },
        createPaymentRequest: function () {
          return {
            requestShippingAddress: false,
            currencyCode: "GBP",
            countryCode: "GB",

            total: {
              label: "Merchant Name",
              amount: "1.01",
              pending: false,
            },

            lineItems: [
              {
                label: "Subtotal",
                amount: "1.00",
                pending: false,
              },
              {
                label: "Tax",
                amount: "0.01",
                pending: false,
              }
            ]
          };
        },
      }
    });
    function submitButtonClick(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      sqPaymentForm.requestCardNonce();
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>My Payment Form</h1>
    <p>github example</p>
    <form id="form" novalidate action="process-card.php" method="post">
        <div id="pay-button-area" style="display:none">
            <button id="sq-apple-pay" class="apple-pay-button apple-pay-button-white" />
        </div>
        <label>Amount</label><div id="amount"></div>
            <br style="clear:both">
        <label>Credit Card</label><div id="sq-card-number"></div>
            <br style="clear:both">
        <label>CVV</label><div id="sq-cvv"></div>
            <br style="clear:both">
        <label>Expiration Date</label><div id="sq-expiration-date"></div>
            <br style="clear:both">
        <label>Postcode</label><div id="sq-postal-code"></div>
            <br style="clear:both">
        <input type="hidden" id="card-nonce" name="nonce">
        <label>&nbsp;</label><input type="submit" onclick="submitButtonClick(event)" id="card-nonce-submit">
    </form>
    <div id="errors"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

# Replace these values. You probably want to start with your Sandbox credentials
# to start: https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/using-sandbox/

# The access token to use in all Connect API requests. Use your *sandbox* access
# token if you're just testing things out.
$access_token = 'sandbox-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

# Helps ensure this code has been reached via form submission
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST') {
  error_log("Received a non-POST request");
  echo "Request not allowed";
  http_response_code(405);
  return;
}

# Fail if the card form didn't send a value for `nonce` to the server
$nonce = $_POST['nonce'];
if (is_null($nonce)) {
  echo "Invalid card data";
  http_response_code(422);
  return;
}

\SquareConnect\Configuration::getDefaultConfiguration()->setAccessToken($access_token);
$locations_api = new \SquareConnect\Api\LocationsApi();

try {
  $locations = $locations_api->listLocations();
  #We look for a location that can process payments
  $location = current(array_filter($locations->getLocations(), function($location) {
    $capabilities = $location->getCapabilities();
    return is_array($capabilities) &&
      in_array('CREDIT_CARD_PROCESSING', $capabilities);
  }));

} catch (\SquareConnect\ApiException $e) {
  echo "Caught exception!<br/>";
  print_r("<strong>Response body:</strong><br/>");
  echo "<pre>"; var_dump($e->getResponseBody()); echo "</pre>";
  echo "<br/><strong>Response headers:</strong><br/>";
  echo "<pre>"; var_dump($e->getResponseHeaders()); echo "</pre>";
  exit(1);
}

$transactions_api = new \SquareConnect\Api\TransactionsApi();

$request_body = array (

  "card_nonce" => $nonce,

  # Monetary amounts are specified in the smallest unit of the applicable currency.
  # This amount is in cents. It's also hard-coded for $1.00, which isn't very useful.
  "amount_money" => array (
    "amount" => 100,
    "currency" => "GBP"
  ),

  # Every payment you process with the SDK must have a unique idempotency key.
  # If you're unsure whether a particular payment succeeded, you can reattempt
  # it with the same idempotency key without worrying about double charging
  # the buyer.
  "idempotency_key" => uniqid()
);

# The SDK throws an exception if a Connect endpoint responds with anything besides
# a 200-level HTTP code. This block catches any exceptions that occur from the request.
try {
  $result = $transactions_api->charge($location->getId(), $request_body);
  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($result);
  echo "</pre>";
} catch (\SquareConnect\ApiException $e) {
  echo "Caught exception!<br/>";
  print_r("<strong>Response body:</strong><br/>");
  echo "<pre>"; var_dump($e->getResponseBody()); echo "</pre>";
  echo "<br/><strong>Response headers:</strong><br/>";
  echo "<pre>"; var_dump($e->getResponseHeaders()); echo "</pre>";
}
enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

First you will need a hidden or text field on the main payment form ...

```
<input type="text" name="manual-amount">
```

Then on the process_card page you will need to grab the incoming form field from the POST data.  (Following shown in Python sorry ...), but pretty much exactly how the NONCE data is extracted.

```
nonce = form.getvalue('nonce')
amount = form.getvalue('manual-amount')
```

Later down the page, the amount is setup.  In that section replace the hard-coded 100 with the integer value of the amount value you just got from the POST data above ...

```
# Monetary amounts are specified in the smallest unit of the applicable currency.
# This amount is in cents. It's also hard-coded for $1.00, which isn't very useful.
amount = {'amount': int(amount), 'currency': 'GBP'}
```

Hope this will give you and others some ideas on how to do this in PHP and other languages.